# Use $\epsilon$ - $\delta$ definition to prove $\lim_{z\to 1}$ $\frac{z+2}{z+3i}$ $=$ $\frac{3}{1+3i}$

Tags: limits, proof-writing, epsilon-delta

So i need need to prove that $$\lim_{z\to 1} \frac{z+2}{z+3i} = \frac{3}{1+3i}$$ So far my understanding is that we want to calculate $\left|{f(z)-z}\right|$ and manipulate it in such a way  that we get $\left|{z-1}\right|$ to appear. I have  $$\left|\frac{z+2}{z+3i}-\frac{3}{1+3i}\right|$$ but no matter what way i manipulate or simplify it i can't seem to get it to work out. What should it like when it is simplified to the necessary form?

Comment: I suspect you mean $z \to 1$ above? Note that the function $z \mapsto \frac{z+2}{z+3i}$ is  continuous for $z \neq -3i$. Then you can just evaluate the function at $z=1$.

Comment: Or note that the expression above is $|{ (3i-2)(z-1)\over (z(3i+1) + 3i -9} |$.

Comment: Yes @copper.hat sorry about that i meant as z goes to 1.

Comment: @DietrichBurde pretty sure you misread the question and your statement is wrong.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I mean you have nearly 20k rep. I'm sure you had a pretty good idea i meant z. As assumed by the other user. Why not just say "I think you have a typo" or something. When have you ever seen and problem like that ever? You were just trying to be a jerk. leave.

Comment: @DietrichBurde So you admit it. You should be penalized rep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note

\begin{align}\left|\frac{z + 2}{z + 3i} - \frac{3}{1 + 3i}\right| &= \left|\frac{(z + 2)(1 + 3i) - 3(z + 3i)}{(z + 3i)(1 + 3i)}\right|\\
&= \left|\frac{(-2 + 3i)z + (2-3i)}{(z + 3i)(1 + 3i)}\right|\\
&= \left|\frac{-2 + 3i}{1 + 3i}\frac{z-1}{z+3i}\right|\\
&= \sqrt{\frac{13}{10}}\frac{|z - 1|}{|z + 3i|}.
\end{align}

Now if $|z - 1| < (1/2)\sqrt{10}$, then $$|z + 3i| = |(z - 1) + (1 + 3i)|\ge |1 + 3i| - |z - 1| > \sqrt{10} - \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{10} = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{10},$$

Thus

$$\sqrt{\frac{13}{10}}\frac{|z - 1|}{|z + 3i|} < \frac{\sqrt{13}}{\sqrt{10}}\frac{2}{\sqrt{10}}|z - 1| = \frac{\sqrt{13}}{5}|z - 1|.$$

We want the last expression to be made less than $\epsilon$ in our $\delta-\epsilon$ argument. This suggests to do the following. Let $\epsilon > 0$ and set $\delta = \min\{(1/2)\sqrt{10}, 5\epsilon/\sqrt{13}\}$. For all $z$, $0 < |z - 1| < \delta$ implies

$$\left|\frac{z + 2}{z + 3i} - \frac{3}{1 + 3i}\right| = \sqrt{\frac{13}{10}}\frac{|z - 1|}{|z + 3i|} <  \frac{\sqrt{13}}{5}|z - 1| < \frac{\sqrt{13}}{5}\frac{5\epsilon}{\sqrt{13}}= \epsilon.$$

Comment: Thanks very well explained, thank you.

Comment: I dont quite understand  why this is true $|z - 1| < (1/2)\sqrt{10}$

Comment: @After_Sunset why what is true?

Comment: How do we get this line $|z - 1| < (1/2)\sqrt{10} $ like what is the logic behind it i dont understand why its happening

Comment: @After_Sunset it was an assumption. I showed that if $|z - 1| < (1/2)\sqrt{10}$, then the absolute value expression you had on top is less than $(\sqrt{13}/5)|z - 1|$. Using that, I can construct the actual proof, which was at the end. Namely, given $\epsilon > 0$, if we take $\delta$ to be the smaller of the numbers $(1/2)\sqrt{10}$ and $5\epsilon/\sqrt{13}$, then that absolute value expression is less than $\epsilon$ whenever $0 < |z - 1| < \delta$, which is what we want.

Comment: Okay so how do you go about choosing $(1/2)\sqrt{10}$ is there some procedure or do i just randomly choose a number?

Comment: @After_Sunset it wasn't entirely random. I want a lower bound for $|z + 3i|$. Since $|1 + 3i| = \sqrt{10}$ and $$|z + 3i| = |(z - 1) + (1 + 3i)| \ge |1 + 3i| - |z - 1| = \sqrt{10} - |z - 1|$$ by the triangle inequality, having $|z - 1|$ smaller than $\sqrt{10}$ ensures that I get a lower bound for $|z + 3i|$. It's convenient to choose $(1/2)\sqrt{10}$, but you could have chosen e.g. $3$ or $\sqrt{5}$.

Comment: Very well put. Thanks for all your help, i appreciate it.